# Asp.net ListView: how to set fixed size for the colum of the table?

Tags: asp.net, listview

i've a 'structure' on a Asp.Net ListView like this (it is an exctract):

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvSchede" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsWrkCtrTable" GroupItemCount="1">

    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" style="width: 100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <table style="background-color: #EEDFCC; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px; border-color: Gray;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
```

......
......

```
 <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
                        border-color: #999999; border-style: none; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    color: #000000;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
```

The problem is that my output are columns with different size (follow the image, i've manually deleted string content for my company's privacy):
[image]

Where i've to set the column size to have it ALL the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to set column width inside a table with 1 column:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <col width="100">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is an example with 2 columns:

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <col width="100">
  <col width="50">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is an example with 3 columns:

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <col width="40">
  <col width="40">
  <col width="20">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Loans</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps out at least a bit.